# Put SQLite results in Java Object

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing a quiz game in Android and I'm trying to save the user's match with SQLite.

I have two tables:

```
MATCH
-id
-description

QUESTION
-id
-id_match
-question
```

I have `Match` and `Question` objectes in Java. The `Match` object has an `ArrayList<Question>`.

No problem with saving datas.

I need to get from database all matches with all related questions.

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM matches LEFT JOIN questions ON matches.id = questions.id_match
```

And this is how I execute the query:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

How can I iterate cursor in order to get an `ArrayList<Match>`?

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT * FROM matches LEFT JOIN questions ON matches.id = questions.id_match
```

will fetch 5 columns and 2 of them have the same name: `id`.
I believe it's better to change the query like this:

```
SELECT m.id mid, m.description, q.id qid, q.id_match, q.question 
FROM matches m LEFT JOIN questions q ON m.id = q.id_match
```

So the names of the columns are all different. 
Now after you execute:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

you have a `Cursor` object containing all the rows that the above query fetched.
You need a loop to access the values of each column of each row:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String mid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mid"));
    String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description"));
    String qid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("qid"));
    String id_match = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id_match"));
    String question = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("question"));
    // here write your code
}
```

If `mid`, `qid` and `id_match` are not strings but integers, replace with `getInt()` instead of `getString()`.

Comment: My problem is exactly where you wrote //here write your code. How can I know if current cursor is a new match or just another question to add to the match?

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question so you explain your problem clearly. As your question is now it does not imply anything that you said in your comment. Also post all the relevant code that you have.

Comment: Every cursor iteration IS NOT a whole match object but could be one of the questions.

Comment: Every row of the cursor contains both a combined row from matches and questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT M.id as match_id, M.description, Q.id as ques_id, Q.id_match, Q.question FROM matches M LEFT JOIN questions Q ON matches.id = questions.id_match
```

You can iterate cursor like this:

```
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String match_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("match_id"));
        String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description"));
        String ques_id= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ques_id"));
        String id_match= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id_match"));
    }
```